# Is it correct to say "amount of fee"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I wonder if writing "an amount of fee" is grammatically correct?

> For example: Imposing certain amount of fee will bring a lot of benefits.

Answer (score 3):

It would be more idiomatic as "...imposing a fee of a certain amount..."

However, as the comment below points out, you could leave out the words "a certain amount", since they don't really add anything to the meaning.

Comment: Really, "certain amount of" and "of a certain amount" are redundant and unnecessary. In fact, (I suggest) imposing a **charge** will bring a lot of benefits.

Comment: I agree about "a certain amount" being unnecessary, but I think "fee" fits a little better than "charge".

Comment: We don't know for what the charge (or fee) is to be imposed. I might prefer 'charge' for something routine like allowing someone to park on my land, but I think I would want a fee for arranging a loan or representing someone in court. In many situations they are, however used interchangeably.